# How to move CGRect in a custom cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

So, I have a custom cell class and in the implementation I have this code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
    CGRect frame;

    frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+10,10, 50, 50);
    picture.frame = frame;

    frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+75 ,0, 170, 50);
    nameLabel.frame = frame;

    frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+75 ,43, 225, 23);
    costLabel.frame = frame;

    frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+280, 30, 8, 13);
    arrow.frame = frame;
}
```

Now let's see how this layout works at the picture below:

[image]

I am satisfied with the result, but I also want to change **costLabel** position in the cell according to the **nameLabel**. If there are two `lines` of text in the **nameLabel**, I don't want to change the costLabel position, however if there are just one `line` of text in the **nameLabel**, I want to move **costLabel** upper, so I can rid off the space and make **costLabel** closer to **nameLabel**.

I tried this in the **cellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
CGRect frame = cell.costLabel.frame;
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y-10; // new y coordinate
cell.costLabel.frame = frame;
```

But it didn't work.

Any solutions or ideas, how can I change `CGRect` coordinates (y origin) ?

Comment: Can you calculate if the text will take single or multiple lines?

Comment: I can calculate how many chars in the string and then find out how many lines.

Comment: The i guess @Owen Hartnett's answer should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layoutSubviews is going to be called when it wants to draw your cell.  Make your frame changes in layoutSubviews (i.e.

```
if (thereIsOnlyOneLineInThisCell) {
  frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+75 ,43 -10, 225, 23);
} else {
   frame = CGRectMake(boundsX+75 ,43, 225, 23);
}

   costLabel.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calclulate the size of the nameLabel with : [NSString UIKit additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)